# JavaScript show/hide divs on button click - multiple per page

Tags: javascript

I am trying to develop a page where there would be multiple divs, each of these divs have a button of which would show a "dropdown" style div below it when clicked.

Currently I have some code which when one button is clicked, it shows all of the "dropdown" styled divs on the page instead of just the one in the same container as the button.

I would like this to be done in pure JavaScript without jquery, any help would be appreciated, thank you!

HTML

```
<div class="fullResultsContainer">
    <div class="resultContainer">
        <div class="resultRow">
            <!--            This has multiple divs but this is the only one relevant to the issue-->
            <div class="resultMenu">
                <button class="mobileShowActivityFeedBtn" onclick="mobileActivityLog()"> Show activity feed </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="mobileDropDown">
            <p> This is the content I want to show on button click</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="resultContainer">
        <div class="resultRow">
            <!--            This has multiple divs but this is the only one relevant to the issue-->
            <div class="resultMenu">
                <button class="mobileShowActivityFeedBtn" onclick="mobileActivityLog()"> Show activity feed </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mobileDropDown">
            <p> This is the content I want to show on button click</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function mobileActivityLog() {
    var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("mobileShowActivityFeedBtn");
    var activity = document.getElementsByClassName("mobileDropDown");

    for(var i=0; i<btn.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; i<activity.length; j++) {
            if(activity[j].style.display == "none") {
                activity[j].style.display = "flex"
            } else {
                activity[j].style.display = "none"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to send a parameter to the method and `getElementById` with a concatenated string with the parameter.

```
<div class="fullResultsContainer">
    <div class="resultContainer">
        <div class="resultRow">
            <div class="resultMenu">
                <button onclick="mobileActivityLog(1)"> Show activity feed </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="mobileDropDown-1">
            <p> This is the content I want to show on button click</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="resultContainer">
        <div class="resultRow">
            <div class="resultMenu">
                <button onclick="mobileActivityLog(2)"> Show activity feed </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="mobileDropDown-2">
            <p> This is the content I want to show on button click</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function mobileActivityLog(index) {
    var activity = document.getElementsById("mobileDropDown-" + index);
    if(activity.style.display == "none") {
         activity.style.display = "flex"
    } else {
         activity.style.display = "none"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the best possible ways to achieve this is to pass the current context using 'call' in the HTML. Use this context to target the required result container(here 'mobileDropDown' container).

```js
function mobileActivityLog () {
    var _this = this;
    var activity = _this.closest('.resultContainer').querySelector(".mobileDropDown");
    activity.classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullResultsContainer">
    <div class="resultContainer">
        <div class="resultRow">
            <!--            This has multiple divs but this is the only one relevant to the issue-->
            <div class="resultMenu">
                <button class="mobileShowActivityFeedBtn" onclick="mobileActivityLog.call(this)"> Show activity feed </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="mobileDropDown">
            <p> This is the content I want to show on button click</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="resultContainer">
        <div class="resultRow">
            <!--            This has multiple divs but this is the only one relevant to the issue-->
            <div class="resultMenu">
                <button class="mobileShowActivityFeedBtn" onclick="mobileActivityLog.call(this)"> Show activity feed </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mobileDropDown">
            <p> This is the content I want to show on button click</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```